# Access: transform rows to columns with many different row-values

Tags: ms-access, rows

Let me start to say that I know that transforming rows to columns can be done with the TRANSFORM command. Actually, I've learned that on this great site, reason enough for me to register :)

The problem I have is that I would like to transform rows into columns without every different value in the row is going to be a unique column. 
I'll try to explain it by an example of my Access table, see the picture in the link:  [image: picture of query]

This query shows products (first column loar_aid), with pieces of text to describe the product. Every product has one value tekst1, tekst2 and tekst3.
But column tregel1 can contain up to 3 different pieces of text for 1 product. I would like to transform this tregel1 to 3 columns: tregel1_firstValue, tregel1_secondValue, tregel1_thirdValue, if you know what I mean.

Eventually I would like to make labels with this table as a source (every column a rule on the label). Therefore the values should ideally be next to each other.

Could someone help me with this problem?
Help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mean that tregel1 has a multivalue data type? In this case I would higly recommend to do not use multivalue fields and redesign the database for many-to-many relations. In this case solution will be quite easy.

Comment: Sergey, I don't know if I understand you correctly, but this query is made by importing some tables form our ERP software. I have uploaded the database to wetransfer. I cannot seem to place the link here, but it is we.tl /tupQ7rgCxs (without the space in between)

Comment: What do you mean by 'three pieces' - there are up to 3 records for each unique combination of loar_aid, tekst1, tekst2, tekst3?

Answer (score 0):

You need a record sequence ID for each unique group. The following relies on an autonumber ID field to provide a unique identifier for each record in the original table to define sort order in DCount() expression.

```
TRANSFORM First(Table3.tregel1) AS FirstOftregel1
SELECT Table3.loar_aid, Table3.tekst2, Table3.tekst3
FROM Table3
GROUP BY Table3.loar_aid, Table3.tekst2, Table3.tekst3
PIVOT DCount("*","Table3","loar_aid='" & [loar_aid] & "' AND tekst1='" & [tekst1] & "' AND tekst2='" & [tekst2] & "' AND Nz(tekst3,'None')='" & Nz([tekst3],"None") & "' AND ID<" & [ID])+1;
```

Be aware this type of query using DCount() or a nested subquery can perform slowly on very large dataset.