# MsAccess - Rows to Column transposition

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

in my access db I keep track of Members who participate in a Committee meeting.
One of the members is nominated President and others can be nominated as DeputyPresident (Substitute) and act as President when he is absent.

At each meeting can participate from three to eight members (only one act as president).

A requirement is to display a list of the meetings with the following layout:

```
MeetingDate - President - Member 1 - Member 2 - Member 3 .....
```

My tables are:

**Member:** `MemberId,LastName, FirstName, President, DeputyPresident, <other fields>`

**Meeting :** `MeetingId, Date, StateId, <other fields>`

**Partecipate :** `MeetingId, MemberId`

How can I query database to have the members listed in column with header: `Member1,Member2,Member3, etc..`

Thanks.

Comment: Search for "PIVOT". MS-access handles it and there are plenty of examples here. Your question is too much "verbosed" to get any answer. You should show your data, actual SQL statements, and desired output.

Comment: At least try the Query Wizard - Crosstab might work for you - THEN come back with your SQL and any results and any change that you need for the output

Comment: You need a record sequence ID for each Meeting group. This can be calculated. That calculated sequence ID will become a column header in a CROSSTAB query. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274815/access-transform-rows-to-columns-with-many-different-row-values/49286932#49286932

Comment: President is not lifetime, but rather may vary for each Meeting.  Thus the Participate table might need to show if that MemberId was President (or DeputyPresident) during that meeting.  Is it possible to have a meeting where no attendee was the President (or Deputy)?  Which would change the expected output?